# How to use gridView android Java?

Tags: android, gridview

I've just started programming in android and Im pretty lost.
I want to make Ladders and Snakes game. I've managed to create a gridView (no a good one though), and I don't know what to do next. I dont really understand how the gridView works,
I want to add a "player" that moves over the grid.

and this is the code I have so far:

```
public class GameActivity extends Activity {
GridView gridView;
int board[][];
Drawable backImage;
int randomNum;
int position[][];
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
    // Show the Up button in the action bar.
    setupActionBar();

    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
    //Instance of ImageAdapter Class
    gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));        
    //ListAdapter a = gridView.getAdapter();
    //ImageAdapter ad = (ImageAdapter)a.getItem(0);
    //ad.onItemClick(0);


    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        final Random r = new Random();
        TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            randomNum = r.nextInt(6)+1;
            text.setText(Integer.toString(randomNum));
            //TODO: changePosition(randomNum);

        }
    });
    newGame();
}
```

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

```
// Keep all Images in array
public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
          R.drawable.pic_36, R.drawable.pic_35,
          R.drawable.pic_34, R.drawable.pic_33,
          R.drawable.pic_32, R.drawable.pic_31, 
          R.drawable.pic_25, R.drawable.pic_26, 
          R.drawable.pic_27, R.drawable.pic_28,
          R.drawable.pic_29, R.drawable.pic_30,
          R.drawable.pic_24, R.drawable.pic_23, 
          R.drawable.pic_22, R.drawable.pic_21, 
          R.drawable.pic_20, R.drawable.pic_19,
          R.drawable.pic_13, R.drawable.pic_14,
          R.drawable.pic_15, R.drawable.pic_16,
          R.drawable.pic_17, R.drawable.pic_18,
          R.drawable.pic_12, R.drawable.pic_11,
          R.drawable.pic_10, R.drawable.pic_9,
          R.drawable.pic_8, R.drawable.pic_7,
          R.drawable.pic_1, R.drawable.pic_2,
          R.drawable.pic_3, R.drawable.pic_4,
          R.drawable.pic_5, R.drawable.pic_6

};

// Constructor
public ImageAdapter(Context c){
    mContext = c;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mThumbIds[position];
}


@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(70, 70));
    return imageView;
}


public void onItemClick(int pos) {
    mThumbIds[pos] = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
}
```

}

I've searched all over the internet already, if someone knows a nice tutorial that could help it would be super nice!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find details developer.android.com

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html